# what is the role of the word "Top" in this text?

Tags: vocabulary, headlinese, learning

came across this headline from New Yort Times

"Obamacare Sign-Ups Top 16 Million for 2023, Setting Another Record"

I'm having trouble interpreting "Top" in this. sounds like that 16 Million is the limit numbers of enrrolments to Obamacare, but it doesn't make sense. I don't know howw else to thing about this: "Top" in this text would that be a toppest mark  of members enrroled so far?

Answer (score 3):

"Top" in this context means *to exceed*, or *surpass*.

In newspaper headline English, that means that the number of people signing up for Obamacare reached, or went above 16 million.

Answer (score 3):

Besides talking about the best of something, top can also be used to refer to the number of signups **exceeding** 23 million.

> I just topped my highest score!

> Imports topped £10 billion last month - Collins Dictionary

> How are you going to top that? - Collins Dictionary

> The publisher expected the profit to top 1500 copies.

In conclusion, top means to exceed when used as a *verb*.

Feel free to look at some of the examples provided in this link to Collins Dictionary. This might help give you more context to the usage of this word.

[https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/sentences/english/top#:~:text=I%20can't%20reach%20the,the%20top%20of%20the%20table](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/sentences/english/top#:%7E:text=I%20can%27t%20reach%20the,the%20top%20of%20the%20table).